# Angular state change in controller

Tags: angularjs, state

I tried the following right in the beginning of a controller:

```
if (clients.count() == 1) {$state.go('client.home', {clientId: clients.first().id}
```

It worked, except the URL didn't rewrite. When I wrapped the statechange in a $setTimeout to fire after 3 seconds, the url was retwritten.

A colleague pointed out that you can use an onEnter in the state instead, this worked without using a timeout.

But why? The onEnter fire before the controller....